# How to implement <ctype.h>?

Tags: c, locale, ctype

I'm trying to build an implementation of `<ctype.h>` with a lookup table and bits masks ([this method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_character_classification#Implementation)). But I've seen in the C11 standard I need some informations about the current locale :

> **7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`**
>
> [...]
>
> 2 The behavior of these functions is affected by the current locale.

So, do I need a `<locale.h>` implementation? How can I manage my `<ctype.h>` implementation with the C standard library?

Comment: Do you want it to work for all locales?  European is easy with multiple bit masks.

Comment: Well, my project is to recode `<ctype.h>`, so, if it's portable (using `locale.h` for example), it'd better. But it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: The lookup table is the common approach. But the way changing locale changes the table is part of the implementation. If you are at school, you should probably ask clarification if the locale dependent effect is part of the assignment or no. If you are at work, the clarification is also needed (implementing locale is probably an order of magnitude more work than implementing a ctype without them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast simple way to do this for 8-bit characters is to have one bitmask for each defined value of LC_CTYPE.  For wide character types you can reduce the size of the tables by some method like a 2-stage lookup.  To be efficient, this will need to be designed for each character encoding.  Having a dynamic lookup on LC_CTYPE would allow adding new locales more easily.

Looks to me like you could cover the Western languages with 16 or so 1-byte tables.  To do everything would take about 50 tables, some of them quite tedious.